# What weapons and technology can be used in alternate history set in late 1980s?

Tags: technology, alternate-history

The plot is as follows: in 1986, after the Chernobyl disaster, the KGB staged a coup against Gorbachev and deposed him. This lead to a civil war in the USSR with some external actors involved.

[image]

In this fictional universe, many things which are hype in our timeline, turned out real: there exists [red mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_mercury), [torsion fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_field_(pseudoscience)) and other similar things from the era, and in fact are the secret technologies developed in the USSR. The army uses torsion field generators, for instance.

There is also a Buran orbiter in space that interacts with the events.

(and regarding the atmosphere, yes, all the army uses the iconic STSh-81 "Sfera" helmets)

Comment: I think this is both a list and an opinion question,  not well suited to the SE question and answer format.

Comment: https://www.alternatehistory.com/forum/threads/military-projects-cancelled-by-the-end-of-the-cold-war.424073/

Comment: I think the question is too broad and to opinion-based. You entered so many "new options" that every question can go into total magic direction. For example Torsion field make FTL with a Professor X character that can levitate possible.

Comment: Looking up back issues of defence magazines like "Aviation Week and Space Technology" or "Janes" should give you an idea where conventional technological thinking was going in the military. In general, electronics and computerization were just beginning to become common in line units, and ideas like UAV's, UCAV's, swarming weapons and so on were still considered Science Fiction, since the technologies were decades in the future. Wild cards like "Red Mercury" or "Torsion fields" are essentially magic, so how you integrate that into a story is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The West was about to field [caseless rifles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heckler_%26_Koch_G11) and [automatic shotguns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heckler_%26_Koch_HK_CAWS). Those were workable, but no longer necessary after the end of the Cold War.

Go into the [SDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_Defense_Initiative) ("Star Wars") files for things that were not quite as ready.

An expeditionary force might bring [Fast Attack Vehicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert_Patrol_Vehicle).